# multiple tinyMce instances not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tinymce

As with the title in Chrome (v.4.1) multiple tinyMce (v2.08) instances do not work. To be exact the first two instances are ok, the others not, and chrome gives this error:

> Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1

Has this happened before?

Unfortunately I can't show you any code because it's for an admin area, I just need some clue for the moment.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue (2.08 as well). The failing line is in getRng() function:
  return s.getRangeAt(0);

Comment: Have you tried this? TinyMCE JavaScript error in Opera (getRangeAt, INDEX_SIZE_ERR):
http://my.opera.com/XP1/blog/2011/07/21/tinymce-javascript-error-in-opera-getrangeat-index-size-err

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as user XP1 noted, at this link you can find resolution for a comprimed TinyMCE source:
http://my.opera.com/XP1/blog/2011/07/21/tinymce-javascript-error-in-opera-getrangeat-index-size-err

But if you want to work with original uncomprimed source (it's just a bit easier), here is the solution:
Look for code "setRng : function(r) {" (without quotes) and exchange the whole function with:

```
setRng : function(r) {
        var s, t = this;

        if (!t.tridentSel) {
            s = t.getSel();

            if (s)              // this block fixed according to TinyMCE JavaScript error in Opera (getRangeAt, INDEX_SIZE_ERR); http://my.opera.com/XP1/blog/2011/07/21/tinymce-javascript-error-in-opera-getrangeat-index-size-err
            {
                if(s.anchorNode === null && s.focusNode === null)
                {
                    t.explicitRange = r;
                    try {
                        s.removeAllRanges();
                    } catch (ex) {
                        // IE9 might throw errors here don't know why  (NOW WE KNOW WHY DAMMIT!)
                    }
                    s.addRange(r);  
                }
                if (s.rangeCount > 0)
                t.selectedRange = s.getRangeAt(0);
            }
        } else {
            // Is W3C Range
            if (r.cloneRange) {
                t.tridentSel.addRange(r);
                return;
            }

            // Is IE specific range
            try {
                r.select();
            } catch (ex) {
                // Needed for some odd IE bug #1843306
            }
        }
    },
```

ONE NOTE: please make sure variables match. I am not sure how it is between different TinyMCE versions BUT the variables are not the same between comprimed and src mutations of the script file.

Take Care and God Speed